# Conf file is unresponsive/nonexisting

Tags: bitcoin-core

[image: Preferences][image]The file says it has no content(47 bytes to be specific) and there's no way to open and edit it. 
Anyone what I'm doing wrong. Mac operator*

Comment: It's not really clear from what your description what you're doing exactly, nor what application is generating the error.  Can you give more details?  Screenshots or even a video could be helpful.

Comment: By the way, this is unlikely to be a bitcoin-specific problem, since bitcoin.conf is just a plain text file.  So you might also get useful Mac-specific advice at http://apple.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I have added some photos now. Maybe you can see something strange now?

Comment: I think it's just that the OS doesn't know that files named `.conf` can be opened with a text editor.  There should be a way to open it manually.  I don't use a Mac so I don't know exactly how to do that.  You should ask on apple.SE about that, since it is not really a Bitcoin question.  (Zero bytes just means that there is currently nothing in the file.  I'm not sure where you saw 47 bytes.)